# Applying CSS to scoped component of Quasar element

Tags: css, css-selectors, quasar-framework

I am working on a quasar/vue app. I want to style the dialog popup within one component. I'm using scoped CSS, and if the CSS is not scoped, the style works. If the CSS is scoped, the CSS does not work. I only want to style this dialog in this one component.

The template code calling the dialog:

```
<div class="-nav">
  <q-select
    outlined
    dense
    v-model="select"
    :options="options()"
    behavior="dialog"
    style="width: 100px"
  />
```

The CSS element is:

```
<style scoped>
 .q-dialog__inner {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: red;
  }

</style>
```

This does not work:

```
:deep(.q-dialog__inner) {
  width: 400px !important;
  background-color: red;
 }
```

I noticed that the global quasar style is marked with !important

codepen: https://codepen.io/kiggs1881/pen/oNoOzEj

Comment: Do you try using class on the component like `<q-select class="bg-red-10" ... />` also you have a attribute `color`. This could also help: https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/4636

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! The class you indicated styles the actual q-select field, but not the popup value dialogue (which is what I want to style). That link also doesn't address the dialogue, but thank you for pointing it out -- ill keep an eye on it!

Comment: You can also use the `<template>` inside the tag `<q-select> <template></template> </q-select>`
ref. https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select#customizing-menu-options

Comment: Check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63324478/6126100

Comment: Thanks very much. I didn't want to remove scoped because I want to style only this dialogue-popup. How do I apply style only to that .q-select__dialog? An ID on the q-select doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to put the parents class in front of the selector like this?:
(If have seen this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72360651/)) and it worked for me inside an expansion item.

```css
.q-dialog :deep(.q-dialog__inner) {
  width: 400px !important;
  background-color: red;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to modify the q-dialog styling using CSS modules (which hashes the class so its unique similar to scoped) in Vue along with their :global tag which is CSS modules version of the :deep selector

```js
<style lang="scss" module>
.test {
  :global(.q-dialog__inner) {
    padding: 0; // removes the annoying padding when using full-height
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
 <q-dialog full-height :class="$style.test"
</template>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.q-dialog__inner > div  {
    width: 400px !important;
    background-color: red !important;
)
```

Comment: Please add more context to your answer. For example why this is the solution and what your CSS changes.

Answer (score -2):

I think everything is provided in the quasar.dev documentation if that doesnt help try using on hover => funtion-To-Display-Popover-In-Specific-Component
there are many ways to counter this problem using scoped is not the only one

Comment: Thanks, Musa. If I could find it in the dev documentation, I would not have posted.